# Set fontconfig to override font for specific Unicode code block

Tags: fontconfig

I'm trying to configure the font to be used when displaying Glagolitic characters (U+2C00 to U+2C5F). The default font is FreeSerif, which is not legible at small sizes. I need the characters to be displayed in Segoe UI Historic. I've tried the solutions to similar questions before but none of them have yielded results. I believe they mentioned the `match` variable. I've since deleted those scripts.